# How to specify JSON element name in GSON if it is different from the POJO's member name?

Tags: json, gson

I understand the purpose of the @SerializedName annotation. This is used while converting the java object to Json to override the default name of the member. Now I have a scenario where the incoming Json has an element with the key "318".Obviously I cannot have a Java member name starting with a numeric. How will I map this Json element "318" to a java member with the name something like "threeOneEight". Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You use the exact same method you used the other way around: `@SerializedName`.

Check this:

```
package net.sargue.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

public class SO36488332 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    @Language("JSON")
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"318\": \"I am a String.\"\n" +
            "}";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    MyPOJO myPOJO = gson.fromJson(json, MyPOJO.class);
    System.out.println("myPOJO.threeOneEight = " + myPOJO.threeOneEight);
  }

  private static class MyPOJO {
    @SerializedName("318")
    private String threeOneEight;
  }
}
```

The execution result is:

```
myPOJO.threeOneEight = I am a String.
```